# Google play store ---This Item is Not available in your country

Tags: android, google-play

[image: Google play store Pop up Message]

I am an Android developer I just uploaded an app in Android market according to client requirement i can download the app  and install it but my client cannot download the app it just pops the message like "**This item is not available in your country**" but i selected all countries while uploading the app,i Surfed internet but i found solution to root phone or to install any software is there any other solution which could help me

Comment: When did you update your app? You know update will take sometime after every update right?

Comment: I updated my app yesterday but i can install my updated app in my phone but my client can't install it

Comment: Usually it will take sometime to update all over the world. it may vary country to country. There are scenarios like you can see the app but your friends cannot see from AppStore, (MAX 2 Days for Android)(MAX 7 Days for iOS Apps)

Comment: thanx for the quick response let me check

Answer (score 1):

[Google Play support says:](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en)

> - You can only change your Play country once per year.
> - When you change your country, you won’t be able to use your Google Play balance that you have in your old country in your new country.

So, avoid Google Play and use another market app. I suggest either:

- [APKPure](https://apkpure.com/apkpure/com.apkpure.aegon)
- [Aptiode](https://aptoide.en.aptoide.com)

Both allow auto-updating apps.

Answer (score 0):

Some years late to the party, and *Android Market* has since been renamed to *Google Play Store*, still:

There's no need for a rooted phone.

Your client should find the appropriate app settings for the *Google Play Store* (or *Android Market*) app, and choose **Force Stop**.  When next run, your client's **Play Store** app will retrieve account settings from a server, rather than using some cached value, and your app should install cleanly after that.